# What happens if AFHTTPSessionManager's responseSerializer fails to parse?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

If AFHTTPSessionManager's responseSerializer fails to parse the response, eg the response isn't a valid JSON payload, what happens with the following code? Does:

- A: The success block get called with responseObject=nil, or:
- B: The failure block get called?

  ```
  [[ServiceManager sharedManager].sessionManager GET:@"blah" parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSDictionary *responseObject) {

  } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

  }];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.1/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/GET:parameters:success:failure:), it's B; the failure block is executed when an error is encountered while parsing the response data.

I just checked and for me, the localizedDescription on the error was "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."